# Php Gdlib image resize memory?

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing, gdlib

I'm trying to upload and resize JPG photos. Once the photo is uploaded I resize it but get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15104 bytes)

Configuration (`php.ini`):

```
memory_limit = 64M
```

PHP :

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "64M");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am i doing wrong"* - Hard to answer that when you haven't shown us what you're doing. How big is the image you're resizing?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the conversion:

> 67 108 864 bytes = 65 536 kilobytes = 64 megabytes
>
> 67 123 968 bytes =  64 megabytes + 15 104 bytes (overlow)

Conclusion: **`64M`** is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

When resizing jpeg images with GD, the filesize often does not make as big of an impact on memory usage as the image dimensions. This is because jpegs have famously high compression and the GD functions, such as [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) will generate image/pixel data that is not compressed. You can probably avoid your error by trying one of at least a couple things:

1. Increase the `memory_limit` even further
2. Check the image dimensions right after upload and if the image's pixel count exceeds a certain amount, avoid further processing.

Comment: gd pixel data is completely NOT compressed. the in-memory representation is a raw bitmap. compression in-memory would only slow everything down.

Comment: @Marc B - That was my guess. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A decompressed image takes atleast 3 bytes per pixel so if you have really large images you can run into trouble. However it could also be  your code that is at fault. Do not forget to call [imagedestroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php) on any image you do not longer need in memory.